# Intellij IDEA not running gradle install

Tags: maven, gradle, intellij-idea

I am somewhat new to IDEA, having only used Android Studio for a few months. I imported a maven project into the IDEA community edition and it seems to build well. However, it doesn't seem to be running gradle install. I need the artifacts in my local maven repository. I can run gradle install from the command line and it publishes to my local maven repo.

Here is my build.gradle for reference.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url = 'http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2'
    }
}

dependencies {
}

group = 'org.secomm'
version = '1.4.0'
description = 'seComm JSON messages'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to manually run "gradle install" in IDEA: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html#gradle_tasks ?

Comment: Yes, I can run the task manually, but I would prefer it to run automatically when I build the jar. It's not a runnable application, so I can't add it to a run configuration, and build configurations don't seem to be available in the community edition.